# Can I set stacked stone veneer on an interior painted Wall with mastic

Tags: tile

This is the stone tile veneer that I want to use can anyone help me.
[image]

Comment: Have you read the manufacturers installation instructions ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend it.

The drywall should be cut out just enough that the cut line will be hidden by the edge of the new stone going up, about 2" behind will work. Add blocking to carry the joint if the cut does not fall on a stud. It is highly unlikely it will not be on a stud. Set new cement board in place where the drywall was removed and use thinset to adhere the stone to the wall. Scratch a coat on the wall with a notched trowel and skim coat on the back of the stone before setting.

Comment: Setting it on cement board like a tile is sufficient ? Would a metal lath be needed or would that just be used in conjunction with tar paper on a wood wall ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan  Yes the cement board will hold it ll up. Whether it is 1/2" Hardie backer, Durock or Wonderboard. As long it is screwed or nailed to the wall following the makers recommended intervals, it will hold anything it needs to. About the wire mesh, tar paper and plywood, There is no reason why that cannot be used on this occasion, other than it is a thicker assembly. The stone veneer would be off the wall about 1/2" maybe more. That combination is typically used for exterior applications.